# How to reference a file in the source code after adding it in data_files

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, py2app

I just started trying to convert my python code into a .app file to run it. I was successfully able to make the .app file, however I got error messages whenever there was supposed to be a picture. It couldn't find the file or directory. So, I put them in data_files in the setup.py like so:

```
from setuptools import setup
from glob import glob

DATA_FILES = [
    ('images', glob('GamePics/*.gif')),
]
setup(app=['Wellness Game.py'],
data_files=DATA_FILES,
setup_requires=["py2app"])
```

I then remade the .app file using the new setup.py but I still got the same error message. This is how I referenced the pictures in the source code.

```html
downstairspic=PhotoImage(file="../GamePics/DownStairs.gif")
```

Please help! I don't understand why it's not working!

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the files relative to the python-file you are loading from. In your case, a simple

```
downstairspic=PhotoImage(file="os.path.join(
   os.path.dirname(__file__), ../GamePics/DownStairs.gif")
)
```

In every python-module (with the exception of the **main**-module you started), **file** should point to an absolute path where that module is located.

There are some alternatives here as well - setuptools resources, and as you are on a Mac, you can also use

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource_ofType_("DownStairs", "gif")
```

But that means you need pyobjc.

The followin `setup.py` works for me:

import sys
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
    import glob, subprocess
    import os

```
ICON = "Cyclops.icns"

plist = {
    "CFBundleIconFile" : ICON,
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.laseranimation.Cyclops",
    }


execfile("cyclops/version.py")

setup(
    name = "Cyclops",
    version = VERSION,
    packages = find_packages(),
    author = "Diez B. Roggisch",
    author_email = "deets@web.de",
    description = "A flexible Laser-Scanner to OSC converter with Filtering",
    license = "",
    keywords = "python pyobjc",
    app=["Cyclops.py"],
    data_files=["English.lproj", "Resources/" + ICON] + glob.glob("Resources/*qtz"),
    options=dict(py2app=dict(
        plist=plist,
    )),
)
```

Comment: Hmm. I did this but it still didn't work. I think the problem might be in setup.py. I tried checking in the Resources folder where the GamePics folder is supposed to be and it's not there.

Comment: Could be. I augmented my answer with a setup.py that works for me.